# child and parent process signals in c

Tags: c

I want to change a code in such a way that when I type Control-C or Control-Z the child process is interrupted or suspended and the parent process continues to wait until it received a quit signal (Control-\). This is my code so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {   
 pid_t pid;
 int status;

 if (argc < 2) { 
     printf("Usage: %s <command> [args]\n", argv[0]);
     exit(-1); 
   } 

  pid = fork();  
  if (pid == 0) { /* this is child process */       
      execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);    
      printf("If you see this statement then execl failed ;-(\n");
     exit(-1); 
   } else if (pid > 0) { /* this is the parent process */ 
       printf("Wait for the child process to terminate\n");  
       wait(&status); /* wait for the child process to terminate */  
       if (WIFEXITED(status)) { /* child process terminated normally */   
         printf("Child process exited with status = %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));  
      } else { /* child process did not terminate normally */  
          printf("Child process did not terminate normally!\n");   
         /* look at the man page for wait (man 2 wait) to determine 
              how the child process was terminated */       
 }
    } else { /* we have an error */  
      perror("fork"); /* use perror to print the system error message */  
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
   }
    printf("[%ld]: Exiting program .....\n", (long)getpid()); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to accomplish this, and what problem(s) are you having with it?

Comment: The problem is I am not sure how to add some functionalities in it such that the child process is interrupted or suspended and the parent process continues to wait until it received a quit signal (Control-\).

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try?